# Use COM interface without type library in LabVIEW

Tags: com, labview, typelib

I'm controlling a third party piece of software using its COM interface, but there is no type library for that interface. It's old software that isn't supported anymore, so getting an updated version isn't a possibility.

Without the type library, I can access everything just fine in VBScript:

```
Set spc = CreateObject( "WinAcquisit.Spectrum" )
spc.TransmitExperiment
```

or Python (through win32):

```
import win32com.client as cl
spc = cl.Dispatch("WinAcquisit.Spectrum")
spc.TransmitExperiment()
```

However, I'm controlling the software through LabVIEW, which seems to require a type library (TL) to select methods/variables (everything gets turned into dropdown lists based on what's in the TL). So I can't use anything in my LabVIEW code.

How can I use this interface in LabVIEW, without a matching TL? Or, is there a simple way to create a TL and link it to the existing COM interface?

Comment: Are you sure it's the type library that's missing?...

Comment: @CookieOfFortune Pretty sure. When I look in oleview.exe it tells me there's no type library for that particular connection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have the actual interface definition (without type library), the easiest would perhaps to write a thin wrapper over this COM class. The wrapper will be with type library and usable for scripting purposes. Getting the calls on wrapper, you will forward them to the third party interface in question. Native code wrapper might done flexibly enough to even take over the "WinAcquisit.Spectrum" ProgID.

Comment: I do know the various methods and variables, there's just no TL. How would I go about writing this sort of thin wrapper? I'm not familiar with writing COM classes.

Comment: I'm very familiar with python, if there's any good guides/frameworks for writing in python.

Comment: You design a new COM object with your favorite development environment (C#, C++, Delphi etc. - I am not sure about Python) capable of producing COM servers with type libraries. There you mimic original server, adding the same methods etc. The implementation will forward the calls to the older server in question.

Comment: I'd try to open that DLL/EXE in OLEView, to see if it contains a type library you can programmatically register. If OLEView can't find a typelib, try instancing an object and inspecting its `IDispatch` and see if the "TypeInfo..." button is available (chances are, if there's no typelib in the resources, this button will be disabled). At least, we'd get some IDL to hack with and feed to midl.exe to regenerate the typelib, if you may. Any other way seems like trying to guess too much at binary level.

Comment: There's nothing in oleview, in IDispatch or anything else under the interface. By "inspecting its `IDispatch`" you mean in oleview, right? Cause there's nothing there.

Comment: I might not have been clear though @PauloMadeira , I actually know the variables and methods I need to use, as I have documentation for the interface from the company. (That's why I can write scripts in VB, etc.) There's just no typelib with the interface.

Comment: @PauloMadeira gave good advice above, but if that were available then you'd perhaps won't need to ask the question itself and LabVIW would be able to access methods/properties without need of magic...

Comment: Well the issue is LabVIEW only allows you to select methods/variables which are in a typelib. Even though I know their names, since there's no typelib, for LabVIEW everything is basically private, and I'm not able to select them. LabVIEW is an unpleasant programming environment sometimes.

Comment: @Magnesium, I don't know LabVIEW. If you have documentation for the interfaces and methods, and if the DISPIDs are fixed, you can define matching `dispinterface`s in IDL. If, on the other hand, the DISPIDs are generated on-demand, I guess you have to wrap access to that component.

Comment: @RomanR., indeed. I was trying to know if the typelib wasn't somehow registered, however unlikely it is to have the component properly registered and not its typelib..

Comment: @PauloMadeira How would I check if these DISPIDs are fixed, or define the dispinterfaces? If you have a link or anything, that would be extremely helpful. Also, it's correct there is no registered typelib. This software in incredibly poorly written (it was last updated in 2004) but it's the only option I have to communicate with a proprietary piece of hardware, so I have to make due.

Comment: @Magnesium, the [documentation for the MIDL dispinterface attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366802(v=vs.85).aspx) is a good start. Each `id(<number>)` is a DISPID. You can try to guess if they're fixed with lower-level code, such as seeing if the returned IDs from calls to `IDispatch::GetIDsOfNames` for a lsit of methods and properties in a random order in different processes returns the same ID for the same method/property. And if so, write it down, so you can define a `dispinterface` and use midl.exe to generate a typelib.

Comment: @Magnesium, for `dispinterface`s, the `id` attribute is mandatory. If you find that they're not fixed, this won't work. I see this is all new to you, perhaps this is not going to be easy. BTW, midl.exe is a tool that comes with Visual Studio, and I believe with the free Windows SDK as well.

Comment: I don't think you can define interface additionally and attach to existing interface pointer. This way is simply a step towards making a wrapper over existing pointer.

Comment: @PauloMadeira, yeah this is new to me. I'm quite familiar with programming, but not in this context. midl.exe generates a typelib, from the information contained in the IDL file, right? So with Paulo's method, I include the hard-coded (if they exist) IDs into the IDL file, a typelib is generated, and I register that with the existing COM interface?

Comment: With @RomanR. method, I would do the same thing, but also write another COM interface, where every function just calls the function from the existing COM library. I can do this also with the output of midl.exe?

Comment: @Magnesium, I suggest you take RomanR.'s approach. I was just hoping there to be a typelib that was not correctly registered.